# Limit membership types to contact types

Tags: civimember

What is the best way to limit Membership Types to a custom organisation type. i.e. If the organisation is of type x, then can use membership types A, B but not C.

Comment: and also to other products i.e. Must have product x.

Comment: Which CMS are you using? (drupal has more options to customize Membership screens via the webform module).

Comment: Unfortunately has to be within CiviCRM, as memberships selected by internal staff using the Contact Membership tab + add new Membership.